# Is pork ok if seared and left in crockpot 1hr before turning on?

Tags: pork, crockpot

I seared a 6 lb pork roast, put it in crockpot, then forgot to turn it on for about an hour.  Then turned on low and will cook 8hrs.  Is it ok?

Comment: "Is it ok" is a really...vague question. Ok as in safe to eat? Ok as in the texture hasn't been sacrificed? Giving a bit more specifics in your question will help you get better answers. (Welcome to Seasoned Advice, by the way!)

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine. There are no absolutes in food safety, only probabilities, and the probability of pathogens growing to dangerous levels should be well under any safety thresholds. Searing first should make the surface of the meat an instant kill environment. It's not ideal that you sat at room temperature for an hour before starting the cooker, but your cooking environment should heat up sufficiently within a tolerable time frame to prevent new bacterial growth.