# Forgot to turn the crockpot on with pork in it

Tags: food-safety, pork

I put 2.5 lbs of salted raw pork shoulder in the crockpot, then added boiling hot liquid to the crockpot. I forgot to turn it on, and noticed an hour later. Then I turned it on. Is the meat still edible, or should I throw it away?

Comment: If the liquid was boiling hot to start, it might still be okay.  What was the temperature of the water when you realized your mistake?  (if it wasn't significantly below 140°F, you should be okay).  Turn the crock pot to 'high' to get it back up to temperature, then whatever heat setting you want to cook at.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23922/67

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't check the temperature, but it was warm - room temp when I put my finger in it.

Answer (score 1):

The USDA provides online [Food Safety Information](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/wcm/connect/8b705ede-f4dc-4b31-a745-836e66eeb0f4/Danger_Zone.pdf?MOD=AJPERES) describing the risks.  You can also call them with questions.

Generally, two hours in the "danger zone" is OK, but keep in mind that's two hours total including time at the meat packing company, in shipping, at the store, on your way home from the store, during your preparation, and any reheating.